# javascript : why missing name after . operator alert appear

Tags: javascript

why in my script written **why missing name after . operator** when I've included a script like this

```
this.switch = function(){
      if (this.status == "enabled")
      {
         this.disable();
         this.stop();
      }
      else
      {
         this.enable();
      }
   }
```

the script is meant to divert status from enabled to disabled

Comment: Maybe because `switch` is a reserved word

Comment: Works in chrome though (at least at the console)

Comment: @Felix: and Firefox (also console).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`switch` is a reserved keyword (for ... `switch` statements!). If you imperatively, absolutely must use this name, write `this['switch']` instead, but it will be annoying to use.

A common name for a function that turns something on/off is `toggle()`.

Answer (score 3):

`switch` is a javascript keyword. Try using a different name for your function.

Answer (score 0):

`switch` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript. You can either use a different name (recommended) or access it a different way:

`this['switch'] = function(){ ... }`

Recommend you just use a different name though, if you can.