# Executing a function with a JavaScript keyword name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute the following code in my script:

```
var current = x.getObj(0);
current.delete();
```

I realized that **delete** is a keyword and is being treated as an operator instead of a function so I'm getting a "missing name after . operator" error. How can I explicitly run it as a function?

Comment: what is `x`? what is `getObj` ?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy That's irrelevant to my question. I'm just using that line as an example. I care about the second line which is where I'm calling the delete function.

Comment: If I write `var a = { delete: function() { console.log("hi") } }` in console and then use `a.delete()`, it works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript : why missing name after . operator alert appear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429584/javascript-why-missing-name-after-operator-alert-appear)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:
`current["delete"]()`